# Get count of different values of string in mysql column fields?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

[image]

when we select multiple values that stored in database as follows 
 [image]

now i want to count no of times  values will be selected means 
from  as above table

```
cloths 2 times
Electronics 2 times
Food 1 time
```

How it will possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

```
select c.cat, count(t.answer)
from (select 'cloths' as cat union all
      select 'electronics' union all
      select 'food'
     ) c left outer join
     table t
     on t.answer like concat('%', c.cat, '%')
group by c.cat;
```

Comment: but there is different answers for different questions?it is not specific to this form only!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this in PHP?

```
$options    = array('Cloths','Electronics', 'food');
$values     = array();
foreach($options as $option)
{
    $total = mysql_num_rows("SELECT * FROM TBL_SHOPPING WHERE answer '%".$option."%'");
    $values[$option] = $total;
}
```

Note that you should use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of the original MySQL API.